# How to stop this from displaying the first few characters?

Tags: vb.net

How do I keep this line from displaying the first 7 characters it finds?

```
For Each u9 As HtmlElement In WebBrowser3.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")
    If Not Object.ReferenceEquals(u9.GetAttribute("className"), Nothing) AndAlso u9.GetAttribute("className").Equals("duration_data") Then
        TextBox12.Text = u9.InnerText
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

I'm thinking it'd go into `TextBox12.Text = u9.InnerText` but I am unsure what kind of code.

Comment: This snippet will overwrite TextBox12.Text for each element that matches the condition. If there is only one element or you only want to display the last one, you should rewrite it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Substring method to achieve this:

```
For Each u9 As HtmlElement In WebBrowser3.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")
    If Not Object.ReferenceEquals(u9.GetAttribute("className"), Nothing) AndAlso    u9.GetAttribute("className").Equals("duration_data") Then
        TextBox12.Text = u9.InnerText.Substring(7)
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Is there a way to not display a certain amount of characters at the end, in the same line of code?

Comment: or more like, everything before a specific word is to not be displayed?

Comment: Yep, you can use the IndexOf method on the string class to get the index of the word you ate looking for. Then just use that index on the substring method.